# how to make customize header and footer to all button in datatable

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

Below is my code.And I want to add customize header and footer in following code.And also when i click on pdf button it is downloaded automatically.But i want to show this download file in browser.So how can I do it?

```
$('#datatable_tabletools').dataTable({
        // Tabletools options: 
        //   https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/button_options
        "sDom": "<'dt-toolbar'<'col-xs-12 col-sm-6'f><'col-sm-6 col-xs-6 hidden-xs'T>r>"+
                "t"+
                "<'dt-toolbar-footer'<'col-sm-6 col-xs-12 hidden-xs'i><'col-sm-6 col-xs-12'p>>",

        "oTableTools": {
             "aButtons": [
             "copy",
             "csv",
             "xls",
                {
                    "sExtends": "pdf",
                    "sTitle": "employeecosting_PDF",
                    "sPdfMessage": "SHAH AND SHAH ASSOCIATES",
                    "sPdfSize": "letter",

                },
                {
                    "sExtends": "print",
                    "sMessage": "Generated by Shah & Shah <i>(press Esc to close)</i>"
                }
             ],
            "sSwfPath": "js/plugin/datatables/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        },
        "autoWidth" : true,
        "preDrawCallback" : function() {
            // Initialize the responsive datatables helper once.
            if (!responsiveHelper_datatable_tabletools) {
                responsiveHelper_datatable_tabletools = new ResponsiveDatatablesHelper($('#datatable_tabletools'), breakpointDefinition);
            }
        },
        "rowCallback" : function(nRow) {
            responsiveHelper_datatable_tabletools.createExpandIcon(nRow);
        },
        "drawCallback" : function(oSettings) {
            responsiveHelper_datatable_tabletools.respond();
        }
    });
```

Comment: do you want header and footer in your pdf file ?

Comment: yes,i want to add it in pdf.

Comment: are you using fpdf or tcpdf ?

Comment: No, I am using datatable jquery plugin.

Comment: You should really consider using the buttons plugin instead of TableTools. TableTools is deprecated, no longer maintained and is in any way less customizeable than buttons.

Comment: @zarana Try to use TCPDF. In documentation you will see how to add header and footer and many more